# What is the purpose of these Schottky barrier diodes connected with reverse polarity between the Vin line and gnd?

Tags: pcb, schematics

On the laptop's PCB I see two Schottky barrier diodes connected with reverse polarity between the Vin line and gnd. What is the purpose of this?

At first I suspected that it might be a TVS or a Zener diode, but when I looked at the datasheet, I saw that it was a [Schottky barrier diode, product number (EA60QC04,) designator (PD13)](http://www.1688eric.com/upload/pdf/2012-9-20/EA60QC04.pdf)

Does this serve as a simple reverse polarity protection? If it was connected in series, there would be a voltage drop and this is an undesirable situation. Was it connected in parallel for this reason it? Were using dual diodes used to dissipate heat in case of reverse polarity?

[image]

Comment: Hard to make a guess without seeing the full schematic. Could be a reverse polarity protection provided that there's a fuse of some kind on VIN+ line, or could be clamper for VIN+ line *(if that's the case, looks a bit meaningless without the clampers for another positive rail)*, or could be a freewheeling diode of a buck converter *(PR82 looks like a current sense and the rail coming from its left-hand terminal could be a feedback path)* provided that VIN+ is coming from a switch (could be on-chip or external). Post the full schematic.

Comment: @RohatKılıç This is a good *answer*. It seems doubtful to me that other possibilities would apply.

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't diodes for general protection as much as they are for keeping PL9 and the VIN+ connector out of trouble when VIN+ gets disconnected, by providing a short-time alternative current path.

Comment: "alternative current path" can you explain this? I couldn't imagine what kind of alternative path there was.

Comment: Alternative to current flowing from a connected VIN+.  Inductors do not react gracefully to abrupt current changes.  The diodes will then source a small amount of charge from the ground that will end up on the capacitors.

Answer (score 0):

These are flyback diodes that shunt inductive kick-back. A good idea whenever there is inductive filtering on the load and/or the parasitic inductances combined with high load cause concern.